# problem: g++ returns stack addresses without warning

Tags: stack, g++

This is an analogous problem already signaled for older versions of g++ where the following function

```
int *fun(int input)
{
    int i1=input;
    int i2=0;

    return i1>i2 ? &i1 : &i2;
}
```

does not return a warning unless compiled with -O3.

in case of the following function nothing matters: the compiler raises no warning at all
Here we are in the presence of  the newer version of g++ with -std=c++17 and -Wall

```
const char* getStr(const char* input)
{
    std::string s{input};

    return s.c_str();
}
```

this seems rather weird  especially  since clang sees the problem: -Wreturn-stack-address

or am I missing something?
why has this problem  not been addressed since it exists at lest 8 years?

I tried  to change this behaviour using -Wall -pedantic -Wreturn-local-addr, no success.

Comment: "why has this problem not been addressed since it exists at lest 8 years?" GCC is open source. Feel free to contribute :-)

Comment: That warning is not mandatory, it is just quality of implementation...

Comment: Note that the higher the optimization setting, the longer and closer the compiler looks at the code for optimization opportunities. This has the very useful side-effect of finding more potential mistakes. Presumably below O3 the compiler doesn't look hard enough to spot the problem.

Comment: Side note: even when I don't plan on shipping with O3 I'll often have an "Anally-Retentive" build target that has warnings and optimization cranked way up.

Answer (score 1):

That's the behaviour of GCC, and the documentation says:

> The effectiveness of some warnings depends on optimizations also being
> enabled.  For example `-Wsuggest-final-types` is more effective with
> link-time optimization and **some instances of other warnings may not be
> issued at all unless optimization is enabled**.  While optimization in
> general improves the efficacy of control and data flow sensitive
> warnings, in some cases it may also cause false positives.

(my emphasis).

If you want static analysis, then use the correct tool for the job.  A compiler's job is to generate good code quickly, not to spend extra time looking for bugs (at a guess, the reason that this has not changed is exactly because it would unreasonably slow down compilation).